# Difficult aggregation with multi index in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, aggregation

Hellow! I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1", "1", "1", "2", "3"],
                   "ID2" : [10, 11, 10, 13, 14],
                   "ID3" : [1,2,1,4,5],
                   "code" : ["T", "N", "T", "T", np.nan],
                   "count" :[100, 200, 300 ,560,500]})

df.set_index(["ID", "ID2", "ID3"], inplace=True)
```

And I need to add "col1" to this dataframe where it will contains:

sum of "count" column where "code" column is "T" for each multiindex

so I need result like below. 400 in 1 and 3 like because 300 + 100 = 400
Of course without solution "This 3 are multiindex" it is for help :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace `count` to misisng values if no `T` in `code`, then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for sum per `ID` to new column and last set `NaN`s if no match `T`:

```
m = df['code'].eq('T')
df['col1'] = df['count'].where(m).groupby(level=0).transform('sum').where(m)
print (df)
           code  count   col1
ID ID2 ID3                   
1  10  1      T    100  400.0
   11  2      N    200    NaN
   10  1      T    300  400.0
2  13  4      T    560  560.0
3  14  5    NaN    500    NaN
```